# Transforming Perl Hash to c# keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, perl

I have a perl script that calls a c# exe. I have the need to pass a datastructure like this

```
 testA => 123, testB => 111 etc
```

I need to construct this variable in perl and pass it to my c# exe as a command line parameter.

I chose do store this value as hash in perl and keyvaluepair in c#.

So, in perl code, I am constructing

```
 %test_id
```

I am having trouble passing it to the program. I tried few things, but it seems like there is some parsing needed on both sides. Like convert hash to string; and then convert string to kvp on c# side. Is this expected or is there a better way to do this.

Here is one approach I tried.

```
 for(keys %ids)
{
     my $key = join (":", $_, $ids{$_});
     $name = join (";", $key, $name);
}
```

I called c# exe with

```
 UpdateCode.exe -add $name;
```

which will be like

```
 UpdateCode.exe -add "testA:123;testB:111"
```

So, when c# code sees this. I have to do

```
   string[] splits = args[1].split(new char[] {';'});

  foreach(string split in splits)
  {
     //You get the idea 
     //split again and construct KVP
   }
```

Seems like lot of code. Is there a better way? I tried Dumper in perl module, but even with that I would need parsing on c# side.

Thanks for looking

Comment: You need to serialize and de-serialize it _somehow_ because CLI parameters are always textonly.

Comment: Use JSON on both sides, there already are libraries to serialize and deserialize.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON).

There are equivalent libraries in C# to decode the serialized data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my %test_id = ( testA => 123, testB => 111 );

print encode_json(\%test_id);
```

Outputs:

```
{"testA":123,"testB":111}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will I still need to write the same code I had for parsing on c# side?